# Using ssh key pair to encrypt files

Tags: ssh, encryption, gnupg

Is it possible to encrypt a text file using a ssh key pair using gnupg?
Where I work we already have our pair created and will be very useful to use these keys to send encrypted files.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of key is it? If it's RSA, yes. If it's not, no.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of security, it is highly **not recommended** to use the same keypair for authentication and data encryption. For example, if a key used for authentication is compromised, it would also reveal all data previously encrypted with it. (I'm not good at at all when it comes to cryptography, but I believe there are several problems from that side as well.)

Besides, generating a second key takes less 10 seconds (and *that* on a five-year-old computer).

---

It *is* technically possible to encrypt data using a SSH keypair, although as @DavidSchwartz noted, only RSA keys can be used for this – DSA and ECDSA can only be used for signing.

However, it doesn't mean you can simply import the key into GnuPG and expect it to work. [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/273998/how-if-at-all-do-ssh-keys-differ-from-asymmetric-keys-used-for-other-purposes/274067#274067) shows a few differences between PGP certificates used by GnuPG and bare RSA keys used by SSH; in short, GnuPG "keys" contain a lot more information than just RSA parameters, and there simply aren't any tools written that could wrap an existing key in a GPG certificate – primarily to avoid the security issues.

The "other" email encryption standard, S/MIME, uses a simpler certificate format (X.509) and there *are* widely available tools for creating a certificate based on an existing RSA key. Finally, you *could* ditch existing standards and roll your own, using plain old RSA functions to encrypt, which are available for practically every programming language and even as shell commands via `openssl`. Digging their own grave is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. Also, as it is noteasy to use our current keys, I will ask to my coworkers to generate new ones to use for the transference of files following your advice. Thanks!