# Convert ssh public key to gpg

Tags: openssh, gnupg

I have someone's ssh public key and I want to encrypt a message with it so that he is the only one who can read it. However, a simple import with `gpg --import` doesn't work because the format is different.

How can I convert the public key (in the format as they appear in authorized_keys) to a format that gpg can import?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are GPG and SSH keys interchangable?](http://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable)

Answer (score 5):

The two keys each [serve a different purpose](https://superuser.com/questions/273998/how-if-at-all-do-ssh-keys-differ-from-asymmetric-keys-used-for-other-purposes), and as a result are [not interchangeable](https://superuser.com/q/360507/13559).

Specifically, SSH keys are basic asymmetric key pairs, much of the values that PGP keys require, are not present in SSH.

You could substitute the missing certificate value [by self-signing the SSH key](http://www.sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG,-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL), but this seems flakey, and cannot guarantee it will import into GPG.

Best to obtain a generated GPG key from this person.