# SSH rejects RSA passphrase for keys created with GPG/Enigmail

Tags: linux, ssh, thunderbird, encryption, gnupg

Last year I created an 4096 bit RSA key pair with GPG / Enigmail in Thunderbird. Enigmail lists me a primary key used to sign and authenticate e-mails, and a subkey used to encrypt e-mails. I exported the key pair to an .asc file.

Now I wanted to use these keys for a SSH connection and exported the keys like this:

```
gpg2 --armor --export-secret-keys [key] > sec_key.txt
ssh-add sec_key.txt
```

When ssh-add asks me for a passphrase, I enter the right one (that works in Enigmail) but it is rejected:

```
Bad passphrase, try again
```

Using the public key (exported with --export) leads to the same error, as well as using the subkey. "ssh -v -i sec_key.txt localhost" gives this error:

```
key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
```

But the passphrase must be correct because I'm able to change the passphrase with GPG:

```
gpg --edit-key [key]
```

I also tried to remove the passphrase completely but then I cannot log into ssh. "ssh-add sec_key.txt" then gives no output but returns 1.

What can I do to use this keys for ssh connections?

Comment: You cannot use a PGP key directly with SSH; see [How do SSH keys differ from keys used for other purposes?](http://superuser.com/questions/273998/how-if-at-all-do-ssh-keys-differ-from-asymmetric-keys-used-for-other-purposes) for details on differences and [Are GPG and SSH keys interchangable?](http://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable) for how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. :) How can I upvote your answer? Or should I remove the question because it is a near duplicate?

Comment: It will be closed as a duplicate after at least 5 people vote so. (What I posted isn't an "answer" technically, but only a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a PGP key directly with SSH; see [How do SSH keys differ from keys used for other purposes?](https://superuser.com/questions/273998/how-if-at-all-do-ssh-keys-differ-from-asymmetric-keys-used-for-other-purposes) for details on differences and [Are GPG and SSH keys interchangable?](https://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable) for how to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it working, especially using [this howto](http://budts.be/weblog/2012/08/ssh-authentication-with-your-pgp-key). Also thanks for the explanation about votes and answers. :) (PS: sorry, I cannot upvote your answer yet, too few reputation...)